# Create a folder during MSBuild TFS Publish

Tags: tfsbuild, msdeploy

I'd like to create a folder during my TFS build process, in this case it's a 'TempImages' folder which I don't want as part of the solution, nor source control.

To achieve this locally I set up the following post build action:

```
IF NOT EXIST "$(ProjectDir)\TempImages\" mkdir "$(ProjectDir)\TempImages\"
```

This works like a charm, except when using TFS to publish to my test environment the folder is not created. 
After some googling, I found I may need to perform this action in a slightly different way, so added the following to my `.csproj` file.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="IF NOT EXIST &quot;$(ProjectDir)\TempImages\&quot; mkdir &quot;$(ProjectDir)\TempImages\&quot;"></Exec>
  </Target>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have done the trick.

What's the recommended route to create a folder on post build / post deployment through TFS for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Both should work. The problem is likely to be that the TempImages folder is getting created in the TFS sources folder instead of the output / drop folder.

You could try changing the `$(ProjectDir)` property to one of:

```
$(WebProjectOutputDir)
$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)
$(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION)
```

The latter two will only work for TF Build and you will almost certainly need to add a relative path suffix, e.g. `$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\MyWebSite\TempImages\`.

You can add conditional logic to your post build event or MSBuild target to detect when building from TF Build based on the `$(TF_BUILD)` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx

Comment: Excellent, I'll take a look at these on Monday.
As a side point, are there any decent places to use a reference for the MSBuild parameters and their usage? I seem to find very little on the subject!

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: At present no! I've tried a couple of the variables without any luck, I get a red squiggly in the .csproj file if I put it in as a post build action at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the build template and add a custom activity after the build succeeds to create this folder.  Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx) to MSDN on customizing the build template.